Using impute_knn from simputation package in r
I am trying to replace missing value using K nearest neighbor classification (KNN). After intensive search, I found simputation package which I can use. The documentation gives the following format:
impute_knn(
  dat,
  formula,
  pool = c("complete", "univariate", "multivariate"),
  k = 5,
  backend = getOption("simputation.hdbackend", default = c("simputation", "VIM")),
  ...
)

However, the documentation does not explain about the formula, and the example is also lacking. Please help me showing the right direction.
The following is the data:
structure(list(Q1 = c(5, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 
5, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 
3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 2, 5, 
1, 3, 3), Q2 = c(3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 
4, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 1, 4, 5, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 
4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 5, 
1, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 2, 
4), Q3 = c(5, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 
4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 2, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 
4, 3, 3, 1, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 5, 4, 3, 5, 
4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 2, 5, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2), 
    Q4 = c(5, 3, 4, 2, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 
    4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 
    2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 
    3, 5, 3, 5, 2, 3, 1), Q5 = c(5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, NA, 4, NA, 
    5, NA, 5, 4, NA, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, NA, 5, 5, 
    NA, 2, 5, NA, 4, 5, NA, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, NA, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 
    4, 5, 1, NA, 4, 4, NA, NA, 4, NA, 4, NA, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, NA, 
    5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 5, 1, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 
    5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, NA, 4, 2, 5, 5, 4, 5, NA, 2, 4), 
    Q6 = c(5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
    3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 1, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 
    1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 
    5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4), Q7 = c(5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 
    3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 2, 
    3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 
    5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 
    4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5), Q8 = c(5, 4, 5, 
    2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 
    4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 
    3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 
    5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 
    4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 
    3, 2), Q9 = c(5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 4, 3, 4, 
    4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 
    4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 
    3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 
    4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 2, 4), Q10 = c(5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 
    5, 3, 5, 3, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 2, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 
    4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5, 5, 4, 
    4, 5, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 
    3, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 4, 
    4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3), Q11 = c(5, 
    4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 
    5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 4, 
    5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 2, 2, 
    5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 
    5, 3, 2, 3), Q12 = c(5, 4, 5, 2, 5, 1, 3, 5, 5, 4, 2, 3, 
    3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 
    4, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 4, 4, 
    5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 
    3, 5, 3, 1, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 
    4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4), Q13 = c(5, 4, 5, 2, 
    5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 
    4, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 
    5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 5, 5, 
    5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
    5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 2, 
    4), Q14 = c(5, 4, 4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 
    5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 1, 4, 4, 3, 
    2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 1, 5, 3, 4, 
    4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    1, 5, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 
    4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4), Q15 = c(5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 3, 
    5, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 
    3, 5, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 
    4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4), Q16 = c(5, 
    2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 
    2, 5, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 
    4, 3, 2, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 
    3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 
    4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3, 
    4, 3, 2, 4), Q17 = c(5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 
    3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 
    4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 
    2, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 
    5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 
    4, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4), Q18 = c(5, 4, 5, 4, 
    3, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 
    4, 2, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 
    5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 
    5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
    5, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 
    4), Q19 = c(5, 3, 5, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 
    5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 1, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 
    5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 
    3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 
    2, 5, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 
    4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4), Q20 = c(5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 
    5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 
    5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 
    4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2, 2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 2, 4), Q21 = c(5, 
    4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 
    4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
    5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 
    4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5, 2, 3, 
    5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 3, 2, 4), Q22 = c(5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 
    4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 
    4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 
    5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 
    5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 
    4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4), Q23 = c(5, 4, 3, 3, 
    3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 
    3, 1, 1, 5, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 
    5, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 1, 5, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 4, 
    4, 5, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 
    4), Q24 = c(4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 
    4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 
    4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 2, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4), Q25 = c(4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 
    4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
    4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 
    5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 2, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 
    4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4), Q26 = c(4, 
    4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 
    5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 5, 4, 4, 5, 
    2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 
    4, 3, 3, 4), Q27 = c(4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 
    4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 
    4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 
    4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 
    4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4), Q28 = c(4, 4, 5, 4, 
    3, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 
    5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 
    5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 
    5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 1, 5, 4, 5, 4, 2, 4, 5, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 
    4), Q29 = c(4, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 
    4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 
    3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 
    4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 5, 2, 
    4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 
    4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4), Q30 = c(4, 3, 5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 
    4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 
    4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5, 5, 4, 
    4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 
    4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4), Q31 = c(4, 
    3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 
    5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 
    5, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
    4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 
    4, 3, 2, 4), Q32 = c(4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 
    2, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 2, 
    4, 5, 4, 2, 3, 5, 5, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 
    3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4), Q33 = c(4, 4, 5, 3, 
    5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 
    5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 1, 4, 3, 
    4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 5, 4, 4, 5, 
    5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
    3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 2, 
    4), Q34 = c(4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 
    4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
    4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 
    4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 
    4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4), Q35 = c(4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 
    4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 
    4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 
    4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3, 
    3, 4, 5, 2, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 2, 2, 4), Q36 = c(4, 
    4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 
    5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 
    5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 1, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 
    4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 
    4, 3, 2, 4), Q37 = c(4, 4, NA, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, NA, 4, 4, NA, 
    2, 4, 4, 4, NA, 4, 3, 4, 2, NA, 4, NA, 2, 4, NA, 4, 3, NA, 
    3, 4, NA, 1, 2, NA, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, NA, 4, 4, 4, 
    3, NA, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, NA, NA, 4, 3, 4, 4, 
    4, 2, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, 4, 4, NA, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, NA, 3, 
    4, 4, 3, 4, NA, NA, 4, 3, 4, NA, NA, 4, 4, NA, 3, 3, 4), 
    Q38 = c(4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 3, 3, 5, 
    4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 1, 3, 5, 
    4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 1, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 
    3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 
    5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4), Q39 = c(4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4, NA, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 
    3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4), Q40 = c(4, 
    4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 
    3, 5, 4, 5, 1, 4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 
    5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 
    4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 
    5, 3, 3, 4), Q41 = c(4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 
    3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 3, 
    4, 5, 2, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 
    3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4), Q42 = c(4, 4, 5, 3, 
    2, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
    5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
    5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 3, 2, 
    4), Q43 = c(4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 
    4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 2, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 1, 4, 4, 3, 
    4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 4, 
    4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 2, 5, 3, 5, 3, 
    3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 
    4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4), Q44 = c(4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 
    2, 4, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 
    4, 3, 3, 5, 1, 4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 
    4, 5, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 
    5, 5, 4, 1, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 
    4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


I finally found a solution to this after countless trials and errors. I though I would post it here in case it is helpful for others in the future.
First, identify the column with missing values.
colSums(is.na(data))

It turns out that item Q5 has 17 missing values, item 37 has 25 missing values and item Q39 has 1 missing value. Using impute_knn replace the missing values and predicting it using the items in the same factor. In this case items 1-5 belong to the same factor (Factor 1), and items 30-38 belong to Factor 6, and items 39-44 belong to Factor 7.
Therefore, we could predict missing values in item Q5 using items Q1, Q2, Q3, and Q4, and so on. I use backend = "VIM" for items with more than one missing value.
library(dplyr)
library(simputation)
data.replaced <- data %>%
  impute_knn(Q5 ~ Q1 + Q2 + Q3 + Q4, backend = "VIM") %>% 
  impute_knn(Q37 ~ Q30 + Q31 + Q32 + Q33 + Q34 + Q35 + Q36 + Q38, backend = "VIM") %>% 
  impute_knn(Q39 ~ Q40 + Q41 + Q42 + Q43 + Q44)

I hope this is useful for others.
